# Strange under-performance of Titan X in memory-bound kernels (e.g. elementwise addition)

Tags: performance, cuda, profiling

I've been noticing super-slow execution times for essentially all of my CUDA kernels on some machine (Fedora 24, GeForce Titan X maxwell), but not on others. **Edit:** I previously gave the [CUDA vectorAdd sample](https://github.com/pathscale/nvidia_sdk_samples/blob/master/vectorAdd/0_Simple/vectorAdd/vectorAdd.cu) as an MCVE, but due to doubts regarding whether that should really be memory-bottlenecked due to the low workload per thread; so, here's a hand-unrolling of that kernel:

```
enum { serialization_factor = 8 };

__global__ void vectorAdd(
    const float*  __restrict__  lhs,
    const float*  __restrict__  rhs,
    float*        __restrict__  result,
    int                         length)
{
    int pos = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x * serialization_factor;
    if (length - pos >= blockDim.x * serialization_factor) {
        #pragma unroll
        for(int i = 0; i < serialization_factor; i++) {
            result[pos] = lhs[pos] + rhs[pos];
            pos += blockDim.x;
        }
    }
    else {
        for(; pos < length; pos += blockDim.x) {
            result[pos] = lhs[pos] + rhs[pos];
        }
    }
}
```

... and suppose we run this for 5,000,000 elements; and launch the kernel twice, ignoring the first run.

Well, with my home GPU, a Geforce GTX 650 Ti Boost, I get 527 usec. This is a bit strange - I was expecting something like 555 usec, by bandwidth calculations: 3004 MHz clock * 192-bit bus = 72096 MB = 72 GB/sec , and 2 * 4 bytes per float * 5M of data. But it's pretty close so let's ignore the difference. The profiler tells me the "Global Load Throughput" is 72.355 GB/sec.

Now, on the Maxwell Titan X at work, I get 232 usec. That's about twice as fast - but the GPU's bandwidth is 5 times as high as my home GPU: ~336 GB/sec. I should be seeing something like 120 usec. And - the profiler tells me the "Global Load Throughput" is 343.271 GB/sec (!)

How could this be happening?

**Notes:**

- If you think I've gotten something wrong with the kernel, please comment about that rather than writing an answer.
- The Titan doesn't have ECC on.

Comment: The vectorAdd might not be the best example for achieving top memory throughput. As a general rule of thumb, in my memory-bound kernels I aim at having two 16-byte memory transactions in flight from each running thread to fully hide memory latency.

Comment: @tera: I just wanted something with as little of my code as possible. The problem is not really specific to this one kernel. Also, it seems vectorAdd does a good enough job issuing 128-byte transactions - for my GTX 650.

Comment: You are implicitly assuming that the example is actually memory bandwidth limited on the Titan X. Maybe it just isn't

Comment: The sample codes generally are not designed for careful benchmarking. At a minimum I would suggest modifying the vector add sample to launch the kernel twice and compare timing of the second launch. This forces all lazy init to complete, and makes the cache state as close to comparable as possible. It may be that Titan X requires manual clock boosting to achieve max perf. Finally, it's quite possible that Titan X needs more exposed work and more exposed work per thread to saturate the memory bus.

Comment: @einpoklum: Note I said two times 16 bytes *per thread*, which corresponds to 1024 byte *per warp* (or *eight* 128 byte transactions). That is what I aim for. Usually already two 128 byte transactions in flight get you to >70% peak memory throughput, with diminishing returns after that.

Comment: This recent thread on the Nvidia forums might also be of interest: [theoretical/real shared/dram peak memory throughput](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/985255/cuda-programming-and-performance/theoretical-real-shared-dram-peak-memory-throughput/).

Comment: @talonmies: Revised my kernel, although my assumption was not that implicit.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Revised the kernel and the measurement methodology as you suggest. Note that the card reports actually utilizing peak bandwidth.

Comment: @tera: Revised my kernel, although it really didn't change much. Also, not really sure how that thread helps - it just clarifies that the theoretical peak memory bandwidth is actually achievable in practice (which I do indeed see with my home card at least).

Comment: Note your bandwidth calculations omit the bandwidth used for writing out the results, so the achieved throughput is 50% higher. The linked thread provides reference numbers, mentions overhead of bidirectional transfer, and notes that core clock needs to be raised to get top maximal throughput.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132736/discussion-between-tera-and-einpoklum).

Answer (score 3):

Your bandwidth calculations are not fully accurate. The [specified theoretical peak memory bandwidth of the GTX 650 Ti BOOST](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-650ti-boost/specifications) is twice as high (144.2 GB/s) as you calculated because of [double data rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_data_rate) transfer (transfer of separate words on both the raising and the falling edge of the clock signal). The achieved bandwidth in the vector add example is 50% higher than you calculated, because writing back of results to memory also needs to be taken into account. This means your GTX 650 Ti BOOST measurements achieved ~79% of it's theoretical peak bandwidth.

The [Titan X's specified peak memory bandwidth](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-titan-x/specifications) is 336.5 GB/s, so your test achieved ~77% of theoretical peak memory bandwidth.

This is [about as good as it gets](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/985255/cuda-programming-and-performance/theoretical-real-shared-dram-peak-memory-throughput/). The remaining discrepancy is due to overhead like memory refresh, the time needed to switch the transfer direction etc.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some to tera's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41558020/6218300), your algorithm has a warm-up and cool-down phase: when having many requests in flight, latency gets hidden indeed, but at the cost of a warm-up, and a cool-down for the last iterations.

If your scheduling is good, you will have a work chunk of 2048 (max resident threads per sm) x 24 (number of sm on the GTX Titan X). Each of which will operate on 8 values. Hence, your work chunk is 393,216 entries. 
For your 5,000,000 size sample, it results in 12.7 iterations (13 with the last being incomplete). The warm-up/cool-down cost is 1 iteration. 
Depending on scheduling of threads (and this is not necessarily predictable), you may run 14 iterations total; for which you could have 5,111,808 entries at approximately same cost (still one warm-up/cool-down). That size would provide you the best performance I believe.

As a result, the incomplete iteration plus warm-up/cool-down could cost about 10% of performance, the achieved bandwidth being closer to 85% of peak if not more.

The minimal run time of a kernel should also be looked at as it might account for a few micros as well. Running on various data sizes should mitigate this point.

Last but not least, the memory frequency might be modifiable with nvidia-smi, as explained [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/increase-performance-gpu-boost-k80-autoboost/).